# Doctrine last record in one-to-many association

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm new in Doctrine and want to use Doctrine instead of Zend_DB.
How can I get a last record from one-to-many assoc. For exampla I have 2 tables - one for user and one for their login datetimes. I want to get all users with their last login.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not direct answer to your question, but I should not determine last login time that way.
I'd rather added new field to the user table, and each time he logins updated this field. 
In this case all the hassle with relations comes away.

Comment: Yes, I make the table for user with the field for last login, but I gave this scenario only for example :)